# Web Essentials 2015 | Only produce minified files and rename them?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-essentials

I was wondering if there is a way to make WE 2015 output only minified versions and to have the ability to alter the name of the output file?

Thanks in advance
Mark

Answer (score 0):

In your bundleconfig.json, try setting the outputFileName to a filename that includes ".min".  Then the .css only file should not be created.  To change the filename just use a different outputFileName than the inputFiles.

Maybe the example below will help:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "css/min/bundled.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "css/source/Reset.css",
      "css/source/jquery-ui-1.12.1.css",
      "css/source/sitestyles.css"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: @MarkBeharrell I found some of your previous Qs helpful so I upvoted them, which got you up to 52 rep.  If you found my answer helpful please accept or upvote it. Thanks!